# Implementation of an Interface with an "anonymous" method

Tags: typescript

Given the following interface `Fn`,

```
interface Fn<A> {
    (): A
}
```

it is possible to instantiate an object implementing the interface using the builder

```
function buildFn<A>( val: A ): Fn<A> {
    return () => { return val }
}
```

Now, using the following interface which is valid in Typescript

```
interface FnString extends Fn<string> {
    (): string
    toLowerCase(): string
}
```

how do I write a builder function to instantiate an object implementing `FnString` ?

**edit: solution thanks to @basarat**

note:refactored `String` -> `string` according to comment

```
function builderFn(str: string): FnString {
    var fn = <FnString>(() => str)
    fn.toLowerCase = str.toLowerCase
    return fn
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create an object that is *callable* and has other functionality, the best way to do it is by starting with a `function` object. However since the native inferred type of the function does not match the actual type you are building to, you need a type assertion:

```
interface Fn<A> {
    (): A
}

function buildFn<A>( val: A ): Fn<A> {
    return () => { return val }
}

export interface FnString extends Fn<string> {
    (): string
    toLowerCase(): string
}

interface Awesome extends FnString { }
export function builderFn(): Awesome {
    var str = ('asdf'); 
    var fn = <Awesome>(() => str);
    fn.toLowerCase = str.toLowerCase;
    return fn;
}
```

Also note that `string` is not the same as `String` and `String` is an antipattern (hence I refactored to `string`).

Comment: Thank you; let me chew this a bit and I will get back to you (String ->string; yes; thanks, I typed this manually in SO )

Comment: This works and according to my tests, there is no need for the `Awesome` interface. Somewhat surprisingly, the cast `var fn = <FnString>(() => str)` is tolerated by the compiler although the function casted is missing the `toLowerCase` property

Comment: How would one implement an interface with multiple anonymous methods?