# TypeScript basic programming : interface issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Just trying to learn TypeScript.

Not sure why I'm still getting below error.

Note: I have tried meeting all the requirements of interface

```
interface Greet {
    greet(name?: Greet): string;
    (val: string): string;
}


class Person implements Greet {

    greet(name?: Greet): string {
        return 'Hello ' + name;
    }

    obj(val: string):string {
        return 'Hello';
    };


}
```

### Error

```
TsFiles/OopsTest.ts(8,7): error TS2420: Class 'Person' incorrectly implements interface 'Greet'.
  Type 'Person' provides no match for the signature '(val: string): string'
8:26:50 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to create a [*hybrid type*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#hybrid-types) then, per the documentation, the implementation should look something like:

```
function getPerson(): Greet {
    let person = <Greet>function(val: string) { return '' };
    person.greet = function(name?: Greet) { return '' };
    return person;
}
```

Having `(val: string): string;` in the interface requires the implementation of `Greet` to be a *function*, not a *class*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe..Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Greet {
    greet(name?: Greet): string;
    obj(val: string): string; // <<<=== `obj` missing
}
```

Comment: .. I'm trying to implement interface with bare functionality

Comment: Probably a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449825/implementation-of-an-interface-with-an-anonymous-method then?